# How does Blender know whether to use compositor output or 3D scene output

Tags: scene, compositing-nodes

So, I am working on a project and experimenting with Blender 2.8.

Correct me if I'm wrong, there are multiple outputs, VSE, compositor, 3D scene etc. How does Blender know which to use? Are they separate outputs or are they one output? E.g. composite, 3D scene OR 3D scene ---> compositor ---> VSE ---> Output?

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts.

Comment: @RayMairlot will edit question later

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. How does Blender know which to use? Are they separate outputs or are they one output?

They are separated thing. You can choose whether Blender to use Compositor and sequencer:
[image]

When you render, Blender save a bunch of information for camera (called render layers). Cameras are specified scene catchers in concept. Those information can be retrieved in Compositor interface for readable value, and for extra manipulate. Finally, compositor node can link to a final output (Composite), which is what you see in rendering window. (You can also choose what you see in view panel)

[image]

#### 2. Is it possible to chroma key the scene?

Yes, totally possible to do that in Compositor. There is a node called keying, you can try it yourself.
[image]
(Notice that Blender knows about the original color of surface. Those hole in violin does not treat as black-like color in Keying, You can't do that in plain video)

Comment: @lpydawa sorry about misleading your question update my answer soon

Comment: Thanks for the information, but how does Blender know to use compositor output, Video sequence output or scene camera output? also, does each scene have it's own separate compositor, VSE, 3D scene(cameras objects) etc?